# Cookie domain with 302 redirect

Tags: redirect, cookies, cross-domain, setcookie, http-status-code-302

Let's say I have two servers:

a) `http://server-a.com`

b) `http://server-b.com`

`Server a` has the following endpoints:

1) method: `GET` path: `/`

2) method: `GET` path: `/do-something`

When a http get request is made to `endpoint 1`, it responds with a header value:

`Set-Cookie: cookie:0834u50lksdjfbuttonmashlkjdsf; Path=/; Domain=.server-a.com; HTTPOnly`

When a request is made to `endpoint 2`, it responds with a 302 redirect to `server b`.

If a request is made to `endpoint 1` and then directly after that another request is made to `endpoint 2`:

Should the redirected request to `server b` include the cookie?