# Mobile Edge For Android, 302 redirect issue with Service Worker and authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-edge, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA site which is working fine on Firefox, Chrome and Edge on Windows, and all of those on Android, Edge (EdgeA).

**The problem**
This much I know from looking at my Azure server logs:

(1) The login POST is hits a Core 2.2 controller which does the authentication and returns 302 along with a standard Core 2.2 cookie set including the authentication token for the user.

(2) The EdgeAndroid browser receives that, and immediately GETs the location specified.... except this GET doesn't include the cookies from (1), so the Core 2.2 system responds with a 302 back to the login page.

It's a redirect loop.

-> EdgeA is eating my cookies!

I can run this perfectly on the above browsers, and the logs show Edge/Windows for example has the (1)(2) sequence exactly as you'd expect, with the cookie credentials in the second request.

The only thing different is Edge Android. I stripped out all the caching from my service worker for that browser and it's still broken - I think I may need to just not run the service worker for it at all.

---

... and my questions are:

1. Does anyone have a PWA which actually works in EdgeA?
2. Does anyone have any idea what I may have missed? Note it's just this one browser which is broken, hence it may be them not me.
3. In case it is them not me, is there a place I have not yet googled where I can report defects in this possibly minor-interest browser?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433221/cookie-domain-with-302-redirect) sounds similar, although that's cross-domain, and my 302 is not cross domain.

Comment: It could be this:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46411192/398513
 -> display:standalone caused old Chrome to open a window after login in a separate window or iFrame or something. If it's doing that, then that could cause precisely this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was the issue.

It's confused because if you install the site through Chrome as a PWA, EdgeA will throw the user to that site, rather than to an installed Edge site. 

Anyway, my fix was to detect EdgeA specifically at the server, and serve it with a manifest.json with display:browser in it. That appears to prevent it crashing.

Comment: From your last post, It looks like you had solved your issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and after 24 hrs mark it as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was caused by the Edge Android Browser interpreting the `display:standalone` directive and consequently opening a "stand alone" window, which does not carry over the cookies from the original browser.

The server logs show that the EdgeA client "drops the cookies" when handling a "login successful" 302 response from the standard Core 2.2 login stuff.

My work around is to serve a specific manifest.json to the EdgeA browser, so that it reads `display:browser`.

---

At the same time I fixed this MS released a new version of EdgeA, so I can't be 100% sure if my change fixed this or if they actually listened to my whining.